# How to display the time and date of the RTC library DS1302 in a tkinter window using a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm new I have a doubt. I use the library RTC_DS1302 to obtain the PC time and store it in the RTC DS1302 using a Raspberry Pi. My question is how to show the time and date in a tkinter window and to update it every time the time and date change, I have not been able to do this. I leave the code with which I get the time and date. In this link you can find the library.

https://github.com/ksaye/IoTDemonstrations/blob/master/RTC_DS1302/RTC_DS1302.py

This is the code

```
import RTC_DS1302
import os
import time

ThisRTC = RTC_DS1302.RTC_DS1302()

Data = ThisRTC.ReadRAM()
print("Message: " + Data)
DateTime = { "Year":0, "Month":0, "Day":0, "DayOfWeek":0, "Hour":0, "Minute":0, "Second":0 }
Data = ThisRTC.ReadDateTime(DateTime)

print("Date/Time: " + Data)
print("Year: " + format(DateTime["Year"] + 2000, "04d"))
print("Month: " + format(DateTime["Month"], "02d"))
print("Day: " + format(DateTime["Day"], "02d"))
print("DayOfWeek: " + ThisRTC.DOW[DateTime["DayOfWeek"]])
print("Hour: " + format(DateTime["Hour"], "02d"))
print("Minute: " + format(DateTime["Minute"], "02d"))
print("Second: " + format(DateTime["Second"], "02d")) 

ThisRTC.CloseGPIO()
```

Answer (score 0):

`tkinter` has function `after(time_in_ms, function_name)` which let you run function with delay. In this function you can update text in `Labels` and execute `after(time_in_ms, function_name)`so it will run the same function after some time.

Example which use `after()` to display current time

```
import tkinter as tk # Python 3.x
from datetime import datetime


def update_time():
    # update displayed time
    current_time = datetime.now()
    current_time_str = current_time.strftime('%Y.%m.%d  %H:%M:%S')
    label['text'] = current_time_str

    # run update_time again after 1000ms (1s)
    root.after(1000, update_time)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

update_time()

root.mainloop()
```

[More of my examples with after()](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/timer-using-after)